# ResultSet only returns one row when more exist in the database

Tags: java, resultset

I created a java class called Executar_Query_Bd_Multiplos_Resultados  in this class as the parameter for the Conectar method 2 values (int Integer1, int Integer2) of integer type.

These values are received by the query:

```
"SELECT DS_ESTRATEGY, STRID_ID" +
    "FROM TB_BKOFFICE_ESTRATEGY" +
    "WHERE IN_STRATEGY_ID IN (" + Istrategy1 + "," + Istrategy2 + ")";
```

The result of the above query is stored in the variable `ls_command`.

In the `Executar_Query_Bd_Multiplos_Resultados_Test` class I make the method call (Connect) and step 2 parameters (179, 319) and command to print on the screen the variable of type String `codEstrategies`.

But Eclipse only displays 1 result on the console. The query should bring 2 results and not 1. Here is the code for the Java classes and the result of the query executed in Oracle SQL Developer.

```
public class Executar_Query_Bd_Multiplos_Resultados_Test {

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    Executar_Query_Bd_Multiplos_Resultados qr_2 = new Executar_Query_Bd_Multiplos_Resultados();
    String codEstrategias = qr_2.Conectar(179, 319);
    System.out.println("Estratégias: " + codEstrategias);

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void test() {
}
}

public class Executar_Query_Bd_Multiplos_Resultados {
//Variáveis de BD
Connection conOracle = null;
Statement stmtOracle = null;
ResultSet rsetOracle = null;

public String Conectar(int Id_Estrategia1, int Id_Estrategia2) {

    String retorno = "#;-1;@";

    Boolean lb_continuar = true;
    //StringBuilder ls_comando = new StringBuilder();
    String ls_comando = new String();

    try {
        System.out.println("Conectando ao banco de dados Oracle...");
        String url = "";
        try {
            //conectando aos bancos de dados
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.5.12.116:1521:desenv01";
            DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(10);
            conOracle = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, "bkofficeadm", "bkofficeadmdesenv01");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("falha SQL >> " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println("falha geral >> " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            lb_continuar = false;
        }
        //String teste = "'BKO - Rep Conectividade'";
        if (lb_continuar) {
            System.err.println("Preparando comando...");
            System.out.println("");

            ls_comando = "SELECT  DS_ESTRATEGIA, ID_ESTRATEGIA"+
                                  " FROM TB_BKOFFICE_ESTRATEGIA"+
                                  " WHERE ID_ESTRATEGIA  IN (" + Id_Estrategia1 + ", " + Id_Estrategia2 + ")";  


            System.out.println(ls_comando);

            stmtOracle = conOracle.createStatement();
            stmtOracle.setQueryTimeout(10);
            rsetOracle = stmtOracle.executeQuery(ls_comando.replaceAll("\n", " ").trim());

            if(rsetOracle.next()) {
                retorno   = rsetOracle.getString(1);
            }              
            rsetOracle.close();
            stmtOracle.close();             
            /*
            Para comandos de Insert, Delete, ou Update
            --------------------------------------------------------
            stmtOracle = conOracle.createStatement();
            stmtOracle.setQueryTimeout(10);
            stmtOracle.execute(variavel_comando.toString());
            conOracle.commit();
            stmtOracle.close();
            */
        } 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro - " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rsetOracle != null) {
                rsetOracle.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao fechar rset - " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            if (stmtOracle != null) {
                stmtOracle.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao fechar stmt - " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            if (conOracle != null && !conOracle.isClosed()) {
                conOracle.close();
            }
            if (conOracle != null && !conOracle.isClosed()) {
                conOracle.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao fechar con  - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return retorno;

}
}
```

Output from SQL Devleoper query:

[image: Query DB Oracle]

Output from Eclipse console:

[image: Console Eclipse Result]

Comment: You call `rSet.next()` once and assign `retorno = rsetOracle.getString(1)` from that single row. What do you expect to happen? And your method returns a single String, so how would you expect it to handle two string values from the result set - concatenate them? (Also, [please don't use images if you can use text](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).).

Comment: Hello Alex Poole, I started using java a short time ago to automate tests. There was a need to do a SELECT in the database that returns 2 (or more values) values. I know how to do SELECT in Java to return 1 value, but I do not know how to use Java to return 2 values or more. Can you help by adjusting my code so that it works correctly?

Comment: corsiKa has shown how to iterate over multiple rows returned by the query. But we don't know what you want to do with them. You are returning a single String value, which probably isn't what you want; maybe you want a collection? (As an edit to that answer now shows; your return type and caller need to change to match though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing this

```
if(rsetOracle.next()) {
    retorno   = rsetOracle.getString(1);
}
```

This runs once

Consider `while` instead:

```
List<String> retornos = new ArrayList<>();
while(rsetOracle.next()) {
    retornos.add(rsetOracle.getString(1));
}
```

This will run until you're out of rows.

If something like this happens in the future, you'll want to modify your query to `select count(*) ...` and verify you get the same result in both the database workbench and your javacode. Then you'll at least know you've got the right query, and it's your presentation that's failing.

---

### Note:

I understand this question is indeed a duplicate of other questions. However, those are difficult to search. I would propose this be a canonical answer.

Comment: Now `return retorno;` will return the value from the last row found, instead of from the first; so the OP still has to decide how they want to return or handle multiple strings.

Comment: Good point. It's slightly more than turning `if` into `while`

Comment: As suggested, I changed the code to: if(rsetOracle.next()) {
    retorno   = rsetOracle.getString(1);
}  For:
List<String> retornos = new ArrayList<String>();
                while(rsetOracle.next()) {
                    retornos.add(rsetOracle.getString(1));
                }  And the Eclipse console has displayed the error message: Strategies: #; - 1; @

Comment: @Kakashi-Sensei No, that's not the suggestion. I'm not suggesting keeping the `if` statement. I'm suggesting replacing the `if` with a `while` and instead of having a single `retono` having a list of `retornos`

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I will continue to search the internet for other ways to access DB.